# How is electromagnetic induction used in power stations?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

All the questions similar to this that i have seen have not answered specifically the one i am looking for.

I know (ish) how electromagnetic induction works in step-up and step-down transformers but not how it is used in power stations.

Comment: Are you asking how [electric generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_generator) work?

Answer (score 0):

power stations contain both transformers (which use induction to step up or down AC voltages) and AC alternators (which use induction effects to generate electricity from work supplied by rotating machinery). the induction processes which occur inside AC alternators are harder to visualize but there's a lot written about that which you can access on the web.